# Issues when setting a text in a text view in Android Studio

Tags: java, string, android-studio, textview

I have been coding with java for a few months and now I have decided to do something with android. I had written a code with eclipse and I really wanted to build an app on that. Essentially, the java code takes two string inputs: a message and a key. After that it chops both strings in chars, changes them into integers (I guess it's the ascii code) and stores them into two arrays. The code is supposed to crypt the message using the key and in order to do that it takes the first element of the keyascii array and sums it with the first element of the messageascii array and so on... Because the key is shorter then the message, when it runs out of characters to be summed (namely the array that contains the values of the key now has a value of 0) it loops back to the first character of the key and it goes on until it has summed all the values together. The int results will be transformed into chars that will be stored in a char array. In eclipse I just had to build a string with the method stringbuilder to concatenate all the chars in a char array and then print them using a System.out.println for the console or a PrintWriter to create a file with the crypted message. In android studio, however, I had to read the texts from two edit texts (one for the message and another one for the key) do all the logic when press a button and then set the resulting string as the text of a TextView. The code works in eclipse but not in android studio, it sets a strange character or it doesn't set anything at all. The code is the same, I only changed the System.out.println with the TextView.setText(String) so my logical brain tells me that the problem is there, but there are no mistakes and when I tell the program to set the text "anything" instead of the String (leaving all the logic behind) it works just fine. What the ??? I am confused, please help me, here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button btnClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnClickMe.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String Message = e1.getText().toString();
    String Key = e2.getText().toString();
    int MessageLength = Message.length();
    int KeyLength = Key.length();

    int[] ArrKeyValues = new int[MessageLength];
    int i;

    for ( i=0; i<KeyLength; i++){
        char KeyChar = Key.charAt(i);
        int KeyCharValue = (int)KeyChar;
        ArrKeyValues[i] = KeyCharValue;
    }
    int[] ArrMessageValues = new int[MessageLength];


    for(i=0; i< MessageLength; i++){
        char MessageChar = Message.charAt(i);
        int MessageCharValue = (int)MessageChar;
        ArrMessageValues[i] = MessageCharValue;
    }
    char[] CryptedMessage = new char[MessageLength];
    int[] FinalArray = new int[MessageLength];
    for (i=0; i<MessageLength; i++){
        while (ArrKeyValues[i]==0){
            ArrKeyValues[i]=ArrKeyValues[i-KeyLength];
        }
        FinalArray[i] = -ArrKeyValues[i]+ArrMessageValues[i]+127;

        CryptedMessage[i]= (char)FinalArray[i];
       String txtr = new StringBuilder(CryptedMessage[i]).toString();
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       t1.setText(txtr);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @omar kahol, the last char is not printable char. Your setting the value to textView, chars will not append like console. Take a string append to string and display the text end of the loop

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla how do I do it?

Comment: I built a string so I am not setting any char, I think I am just setting a Sring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because last char is display in to the textview, because your setting the (char)text in textview inside the loop append to string and settext(string). And more over textview will not display bell chars.

I updated answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button btnClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnClickMe.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String Message = e1.getText().toString();
    String Key = e2.getText().toString();
    int MessageLength = Message.length();
    int KeyLength = Key.length();

    int[] ArrKeyValues = new int[MessageLength];
    int i;

    for ( i=0; i<KeyLength; i++){
        char KeyChar = Key.charAt(i);
        int KeyCharValue = (int)KeyChar;
        ArrKeyValues[i] = KeyCharValue;
    }
    int[] ArrMessageValues = new int[MessageLength];


    for(i=0; i< MessageLength; i++){
        char MessageChar = Message.charAt(i);
        int MessageCharValue = (int)MessageChar;
        ArrMessageValues[i] = MessageCharValue;
    }
    char[] CryptedMessage = new char[MessageLength];
    int[] FinalArray = new int[MessageLength];
    String txtr = "";
    for (i=0; i<MessageLength; i++){
        while (ArrKeyValues[i]==0){
            ArrKeyValues[i]=ArrKeyValues[i-KeyLength];
        }
        FinalArray[i] = -ArrKeyValues[i]+ArrMessageValues[i]+127;

        CryptedMessage[i]= (char)FinalArray[i];
        txtr+ = CryptedMessage[i];
    }
       TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       t1.setText(txtr);
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Now I do understand the issue :) the code works.